# How to override tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: to adjust section headers of static UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm playing with storyboards and for one controller I set up a `UITableView` that consists of two sections.  In both sections I have added a couple of **static** cells.
However, depending on code paths, I would like to show different **headers** for my two sections.
As there is no source and no delegate involved, how am I supposed to override `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` ?

Comment: Why is this tagged monotouch? The question doesn't indicate that you are using this.

Comment: I am, but I also use ObjectiveC. So a solution in either language will be fine and help me to translate it into the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With static table views you can (and must) still connect the datasource to a UITableViewController. The key is that if you implement the datasource methods then this will override the static content you have set up in the table view. You can override titleForHeader without any problems since this is what you want to do.

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return @"HELLO!";
    else {
        return [super tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    }
}
```

Sets the title of section 0 in the static table to HELLO!, overriding the title set in the xib. The others are left as the were in the xib.

The key point is that static tables are populated exactly the same way as dynamic tables, except that UITableViewController implements its own versions of all the datasource methods. These methods presumably read the information from the xib file and send back the appropriate information to the table view. If you want the static content, don't implement or call super. If you want your own content, use code similar to that above.

Comment: How is it possible to create outlets for header titles?

Comment: You can't, that was a guess as I was away from the mac. I've tested the method in my answer now though and this works fine.

Comment: Great, thanks! Now I have to find a way to port this to MonoTouch.
In your solution, have you made the controller to be the source and then just override this one method? Or did you create an instance of a separate source?

Comment: The view controller is the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, perhaps i need some more info. are you saying that in storyboard you had a view controller and dragged a table view object onto that view controller?

if thats the case then this view controller would still be able to be that table view's data source and delegate

in your .h file:
@interface VIEWCONTROLLERNAME: UIViewController < UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

in your .m file you would need to declare the required methods for each of those:
cellForRowAtIndexPath, and numberOfRowsInSection (refer to documentation for required and optional messages) to avoid "incomplete implementation error". this is also where you could override titleForHeaderInSection.

and back in storyboard you would right-click on the table view and drag the data-source and delegate option to your view controller (or do so in the Connections Inspector tab)

if this is not what your doing please provide some more info.

Comment: The questioner is using static content in the table view. With this you dont have to implement the datasource methods.

Comment: completely agree. but i would assume he's using static data because he didn't know he could implement the data source protocol.

Comment: No, I'm using static content because the content is static! :-) That's the whole advantage of the new static cells. However I'm wondering if there is a way to have influence on the static.