# MonoTouch: how to use UITableViewController as data source for UITableView?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uikit

I'm using storyboards and table views with static content. Internally it seems as if the `UITableViewController` implicitly becomes the source of the `UITableView`.

If I now want to take influence on the static content, I will have to override methods of the table source. In ObjectiveC I can just place

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return @"HELLO!";
    else {
        return [super tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    }
}
```

in my controller and the method will be overridden. But in MonoTouch this does not work.
Please note that I do NOT want create a new instance of a delegate or a data source. With static cells, the controller *is* the source/delegate. In ObjectiveC this is done by making the controller implement the corresponding protocols.

Here is the question I asked related to this topic but now I'm stuck converting the solution to MonoTouch:

[How to override tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: to adjust section headers of static UITableViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691157/how-to-override-tableviewtitleforheaderinsection-to-adjust-section-headers-of/10692062#comment13896288_10692062)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution in the great tutorials on Xamarin's website: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Events%2c_Protocols_and_Delegates

The "`Export`" attribute does the trick!

```
public partial class TestController : UITableViewController
    {
        public TestController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
        }

        [Export("tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:")]
        public string TitleForHeaderInSection(UITableView oTableView, int iSection)
        {
            return "TEST";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it with `[Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]` but it is never called. Do you add something more?

Comment: @testing you will have to set the controller as the `WeakDelegate` or `WeakSource` - don't remember the exact property.

Comment: `WeakDelegate` says something to me. I'll try that the next time I need that.

Answer (score -1):

In Mono Touch you have to create a DataSource Delegate.

Like the demo in this blogpost: http://sabonrai.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/monotouch-sample-code-uitableview/

```
        public override string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
        //do your stuff 
        }
```

If you want to customize the title for the header sections just override titleForHeaderInSection in you TableViewDelegate.

Comment: I know. But in the particular case, the UITableViewController _is_ the delegate. So I don't want to create another one. I just want to tell my controller somehow that it implemented the protocol.

Comment: In .NET is not possible to have a class which inherits by multiple classes. Only with multiple Interfaces, but the UITableViewDataSource is not an interface. So you alwas have to create a seperate delegate for the UITableView. In Objective-C it is possible to have a class which implements more than one protocol. See also this documentation http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Events,_Protocols_and_Delegates "Protocols Deep dive"