# iOS static table view not so static

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm developing a static grouped table view with storyboard. Anyway, sometimes I'd like not to display some of the rows. As long as the rows I want to hide are in the middle, I can set the height of that specific cell to 0 and the trick works :)

Anyway, when I want to hide the last cell of a group (I'm using a grouped table view), my trick obviously does not work. That's because the previous cell won't get the round corners typical of the last cell. Is there another trick that can help me with this issue?

Comment: See my answer here for detail that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691157/how-to-override-tableviewtitleforheaderinsection-to-adjust-section-headers-of/10692062#10692062 the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem implementing the method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

even if I'm using a static table view.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to remove a cell from a table view after it has been rendered is to use the UITableView method called deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: . Here is a code sample:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[myCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: I don't want to delete a row after is already rendered. I want to display that row only sometimes. Imagine a master-detail iPad app. Selecting some row in the master controller I'd like to display in the detail the full table view. Selecting another row in the master, I'd like to display the same table view in the detail but with a row less.